# Restoring backups from SD

Tags: external-sd, restore, titanium-backup

Using Titanium Backup I backed up apps + data to the SD card and see they are still there. I flashed a new ROM. I installed TB again but am having trouble restoring the apps. It can’t find the backups, how do I change it? I went to menu > preferences > backup folder location > Storage provider > DocumentProvider storage > naviagated to correct location > pressed “select” 
Then the list populates with backups but the “use the current folder” is greyed out. I can only click cancel. However if I make a new folder and navigate there, the “use the current folder” is clickable. 
After clicking select the message quickly flashes “Access granted. Please create/choose subdirectory for your backups”

How do I resotre backups located on SD card? I named the folder myself so it’s not like the default. I'm on ROM that is based on Android Nougat 7.1

Comment: If the above suggestion didn't help try instead with *File system storage*,  instead of *Document Provider*

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman well that was awfully unintuitive

Comment: It's been my observation sometimes I need to install an app (from the Play Store) before I can restore the data. For example, when I did find the right backup, the restore button was simply missing, but after I rebooted the phone and installed it from the Play Store, I was able to restore the data with TiB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to successfully select a backup directory via the **DocumentProvider** storage, you should not navigate to the chosen folder *immediately after choosing the abovementioned storage*.

What you should do, is to navigate *only* to the root directory of the external SD card and then tap on **Select**. Next, after the **Access granted** popup appears, use Titanium Backup's built-in file explorer to navigate to the chosen backup directory, and then tap on **Use the current folder**.

Answer (score -3):

If you changed(upgrade) rom version customizingly i.e. Kitkat to lollipop.... 
Then titanium backup fail to restoring the app and data....
If you want to restore backup any how then you have to flash previous rom....

Comment: I can't understand you.

Comment: My ROM is AICP12.1 with Nougat, and I can restore backups from CM13 (Marshmallow), therefore your assumption is invalid.

Comment: I've been using TiBu for years, and it *always* restored apps & data for me, including after ROM upgrades and even after switching to completely different ROMs (e.g. from stock 4.1 to Cyanogen 4.3). It never failed me from 2.1 up to 5.1 – and though I didn't try yet, I doubt it will fail me on 6+ either. So while according to Aristotle one can derive everything from a wrong assumption, this is definitely wrong altogether.